# SQL - One Table with Two Date Columns. Count and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, unpivot

I have a table (vOKPI_Tickets) that has the following columns:

> |CreationDate | CompletionDate|

I'd like to get a count on each of those columns, and group them by date. It should look something like this when complete:

> | Date | Count-Created | Count-Completed |

I can get each of the counts individually, by doing something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(TicketId)
FROM vOKPI_Tickets
GROUP BY CreationDate
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(TicketId)
FROM vOKPI_Tickets
GROUP BY CreationDate
```

How can I combine the output into one table?  I should also note that this will become a View.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Can either of the dates be null?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple generic approach:

```
select
coalesce(crte.creationdate, cmpl.CompletionDate) as theDate,
crte.cnt as created,
cmpl.cnt as completed
from
(select creationdate, count (*) as cnt from vOKPI_Tickets where creationdate  is not null group by creationdate) crte
full join
(select CompletionDate, count (*) as cnt from vOKPI_Tickets where CompletionDate  is not null group by CompletionDate) cmpl
on crte.creationdate  = cmpl.CompletionDate
```

Comment: This seems to be working so far.  I'll do some testing and then come back and mark the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot and aggregate.  A general method is:

```
select dte, sum(created), sum(completed)
from ((select creationdate as dte, 1 as created, 0 as completed
       from vOKPI_Tickets
      ) union all
      (select completed as dte, 0  created, 1 as completed
       from vOKPI_Tickets
      ) 
     ) t
group by dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `cross apply` for this:

```
select d.dt, sum(d.is_completed) count_created, sum(d.is_completed) count_completed
from vokpi_tickets t
cross apply (values (creationdate, 1, 0), (completion_date, 0, 1)) as d(dt, is_created, is_completed)
where d.dt is not null
group by d.dt
```